# Function of Measurable Set Continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, lebesgue-measure, self-learning

I am aware that applying the topological definition of continuity is very useful versus other methods like epsilon-delta, e.g. as in $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x^2$.

I am a bit uneasy when functions of measurable sets are involved though. The most common example I've seen is:

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be Lebesgue measurable and define the measure to be $m(E)$. Let $f = m(A \cap B(r, 0))$, where $B$ is an open ball. If $r \in (0, \infty)$ then $f$ is continuous. Could we prove this using the topological definition?

**My idea:** We have

$$f^{-1}(A \cap B(r, 0)) = f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B(r, 0)).$$

The inverse image of an open set is open, so $f^{-1}(B(r, 0))$ open. But what about $f^{-1}(A)$?

Comment: But $A\cap B(r,0)$ is not a subset of $[0,\infty]$. Why are you considering its preimage by $f$?

Comment: $f : \mathbb{R}_{> 0} \to \mathbb{R}$. So don't we need to show for every open subset its inverse image $f^{-1}$ is an open subset in $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$?

Comment: Technically, $f:(0,\infty)\to \Bbb R\cup\{\infty\}$. However, as I've already said, $A\cap B(r,0)$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: $m(E)?\,\,\,\,$